# Give Bert an input and ask him to predict. In this input, can Bert apply the first word prediction result to all subsequent predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to make predictions with Bert, where the prediction of subsequent words in the first input of each paragraph may be aided, so can Bert make use of previous predictions in subsequent predictions like an autoregressive language model?